# why was my question edited completely

Tags: discussion

[My previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/737507/i-need-a-download-that-works-this-14-04-is-filled-with-errors-and-has-screwed-my) was edited to remove 90% of the problems and errors that occurred while trying to install ubuntu, Who did it and why, if you delete the problems I type out how am I supposed to get the answers, is this what this community does to hide the major problems in your software/or the major problems in the description of how to install the software properly is incomplete as I have now been informed. how does this help any one?

Comment: Please use META for complaints about editing. And I will assume you are wrong here... you do not even include a link to the question you are talking about making us guess to what the heck you are talking about. You need to make sure your questions are up to standard.

Comment: @Rinzwind It is quite easy to guess. Lot's of rant has been really removed.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/737507/i-need-a-download-that-works-this-14-04-is-filled-with-errors-and-has-screwed-my

Comment: @Pilot6 sure not not MY task to provide the correct information and he seems to have a problem with editing so why should I bother editing it in? :=D and yes angryatlyinglinuxusers you are the one in the wrong ;-)

Comment: And there are comments under that question that explain the editions.

Comment: @angryatlyinglinuxusers I would advice the following: remove this topic. Remove the other topic. Create a new topic and stick to what matters: the problem.

Comment: A review of the question doesn't indicate actual problems were edited out, just the tantrum.

Comment: @ElderGeek you had to edit the question hmm? :-)

Comment: @Rinzwind I couldn't resist.

Comment: Like, 90% of his question was pure, ineligible rant. Make a decent question or we won't be able to answer.

Comment: @angryatlyinglinuxusers you are still not focusing on fixing a problem but on only things you do not like or disagree with or whatever. Drop the attitude.  YOU are the troll here. Not only from the way you created the question but your name itself is. YOU are the one wrong here.

Comment: @angryatlyinglinuxusers We get ~200 questions a day and we don't have the man power to even process them all. The rate limit and ban system is in place so we help the people that care enough to actually write good, answerable questions. Your continued rudeness and ad-hominems don't help your case and at this point you're not likely to get much help. If you want you can start over and try https://ubuntuforums.org but you should first fix your attitude.

Comment: You see, for everyone else we know of (except for you), Ubuntu works exactly as described. You blame Ubuntu right away but don't seem to wonder why no one else has had any of these problems with it to the degree you describe. Usually, someone would start to think hardware is the issue, but you seem to think everything that doesn't work for you is some conspiracy meant to target your specifically. Seriously? Grow up; you're not the center of the universe.

Answer (score 12):

Counter question: why should it NOT be just closed and deleted?

It was 1 big rant and full of needless text. I myself would have left it as is and voted to close it.

Ask Ubuntu questions need to be to the point, as short as possible with the most amount of useful information. Nothing more. Nothing less. You want a problem solved? Then focus on the problem and leave all the crap out of the question.

Comment: ***Slowly stands up and applauses while tears roll down***

Comment: However, answers usually get the most upvotes if they are needlessly long and detailed :p.